# Google Chrome table problems

Tags: google-chrome, resolution, css-tables

[Table menu html/css](http://detayhosting.com/problem/)

[image: Table menu 95% bug 901x557]

This problem is just Google Chrome.
Right menu have responsive height 95%,
but some resolution (901x557,901x582,....) menu have bug height 95%.
This resolution on Chrome, menu bottom is 1px empty.
I try display inline-table or block.
First link table, second link inline-block;
second link problem is some resolutions height is broken; 
second link : detayhosting.com/problem2.